# Any format to UNIX end line format recursively

Tags: perl, line-endings

I have two different script to change `DOS2UNIX` and `MAC2UNIX` endline format

**DOS2UNIX:**  `perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/;' < dos1.txt > dos2.txt`

**MAC2UNIX:**  `perl -p -e 's/\r/\n/g' < mac1.txt > mac2.txt`

Is there anyway get these functionalities in a signle command to change `EOL UNIX` format!

Thanks

Comment: what's wrong with the `dos2unix` and `mac2unix` commands? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: not available and does have any previllage to install them

Comment: what does recursive (in your title) have to do with it? As an alternate solution, make aliases stored in the appropriate `.profile or .bash_rc or ...?` file, like `alias DOS2UNIX="perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/;'"` and then supply your inputfile and redirection after it? Or are you saying you can't install perl on your machine either? Good luck.

Comment: The `-i` option is not useful with redirected input. If specifies in-place editing of the files named on the command line.

Comment: If you don't have permission to install them, how do you have permission to install a Perl program? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This handles both cases.

```
perl -pe 's/\r\n?/\n/g'
```

It (semi-obviously) does the wrong thing if you have a DOS file with a bare CR somewhere within a line, which should (perhaps) not be converted to LF.

Comment: Thanks! I have already got the answer `perl -pe 's/\r?\n|\r/\n/g'`

Comment: I bet mine is faster, though, as it will only try to replace when there is something which needs to be replaced.  (Yours will do a number of no-op `\n` -> `\n` substitutions if you run it on a file which is already in Unix format.)